# Azure storage REST group transactions - one of the request inputs is out of range

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying my hand at entity group transactions with a very simple request, but keep getting a "400 (one of the request inputs is out of range)" error code in the response. Here's the string-serialized `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://127.0.0.1:10002/$batch?', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  x-ms-date: Tue, 21 Oct 2014 18:49:09 GMT
  x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
  Authorization: SharedKeyLite devstoreaccount1:vdQ+5/Kmw43u+DcqpWCX14n24WG8hsubtTK5pnK1xO8=
  Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_f351702c-c8c8-48c6-af2c-91b809c651ce
  Content-Length: 212
}
```

And the string-serialized request content:

```
--batch_f351702c-c8c8-48c6-af2c-91b809c651ce
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET http://127.0.0.1:10002/batchTable() HTTP/1.1

--batch_f351702c-c8c8-48c6-af2c-91b809c651ce--
```

The response from the server:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'One of the request inputs is out of range.', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  x-ms-request-id: 43fea847-2226-4dcf-ad62-bdb7cc0af256
  Date: Wed, 22 Oct 2014 00:00:06 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Length: 325
  Content-Type: application/xml
}
```

response content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>OutOfRangeInput</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">One of the request inputs is out of range.
RequestId:43fea847-2226-4dcf-ad62-bdb7cc0af256
Time:2014-10-22T00:00:06.3046099Z</m:message></m:error>
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Edit: Messing up the authorization header doesn't cause a `403` error, in case that helps.

Edit 2: I also get no error if I try batching a single insert - but the insert also doesn't take place:

```
Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/$batch?', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/atom+xml
  x-ms-date: Wed, 22 Oct 2014 16:38:34 GMT
  x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
  DataServiceVersion: 1.0
  MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
  Authorization: SharedKeyLite devstoreaccount1:Eb4JHmCsuL6aLMTGEWs+gt23zbKjAdYjO12YmeYHjf0=
  Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_boundary
  Content-Length: 1008
}
```

Content.ToString():

```
--batch_boundary
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_boundary"
Content-Length: 885

--changeset_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/batchTable? HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 1
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=entry
Content-Length: 559

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title />
  <updated>2014-10-22T16:38:34.6393109Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <id />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:PartitionKey m:type="Edm.String">foo</d:PartitionKey>
      <d:RowKey m:type="Edm.String">foo</d:RowKey>
      <d:IntVal m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:IntVal>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
--changeset_boundary--
--batch_boundary--
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post the server's response as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the URI was `http://127.0.0.1:10002/$batch` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/$batch`. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using an older version of Azure Storage Emulator, which does not support 2014-02-14 version. Could you please make sure your Emulator version is at least 3.2? If it is not, please upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: v3.3.0.0, unfortunately :(. I've added more info to the original post.